# How to use gdal exceptions in .NET?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, .net

I'm converting a `.vrt` to a `.tif` with `Gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName()`. I know the `.vrt` has been calculated to a size that causes an integer overflow error during warping because the command line version outputs the following:

`Creating output file that is 182543P x 514827L.`

`Processing somefile_1.vrt: 0...10...ERROR 1: Integer overflow : nDstXSize=22817, nDstYSize=32177`.

However, the .NET function returns a null dataset and an empty message in its callback. I would like to be able to capture the above messages and throw an exception when this happens. How do I do this? Here is what I've tried:

```
var warpOptions = new GDALWarpAppOptions(new string[]
                  {
                       "-s_srs", $"{_s_srs}",
                       "-t_srs", $"{_t_srs}",
                       "-wm", "6144", // this causes the error
                       "-co", "BIGTIFF=YES", "-co", "NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS", 
                       "-co", "TILED=YES", "-co", "COMPRESS=LZW",
                       "-wo", "NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS",
                       "-multi",
                       "-dstalpha",
                       "-overwrite",
                  }))

var ds = Gdal.Open(vrt, Access.GA_ReadOnly)
var ptr = new[] { Dataset.getCPtr(ds).Handle };
var gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(ptr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var dss = new SWIGTYPE_p_p_GDALDatasetShadow(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), false, null);

var handler = new GdalErrorHandler();
Gdal.PushErrorHandler(handler.GdalErrorHandlerFunc);
Gdal.UseExceptions();

var warpTif = Gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(tif, 1, dss, warpOptions,
                           GdalProgressFunc, $"Warping {vrtName}:")

if (warpTif is null)
{
    var e1 = Gdal.GetLastErrorMsg(); // this is always an empty string
    var e2 = handler.ErrorMessage; // this is always an empty string
    throw new Exception("Error in Gdal Warp:" + e1 + e2);
}
```

Here is the progress function delegate:

```
public int GdalProgressFunc(double Complete, IntPtr Message, IntPtr Data)
{
    var complete = Complete * 100;
    var data = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Data);
    var message = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Message);
    if (Message != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // This will print the "Processing 'somefile.vrt':0...10..." message
        Log.Info(message);
        return 1;
    }
    if (Data != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // This will print my custom callback data string
        Log.Info(data)
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my error handler delegate:

```
public class GdalErrorHandler()
{
    public int ErrorLevel { get; set; }
    public int ErrorNumber { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public void GdalErrorHandlerFunc(int errLvl, int errNum, IntPtr errMessage)
    {
        ErrorLevel = errLvl;
        ErrorNumber = errNum;
        ErrorMessage = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errMessage);
    }
}
```